# SonarQube - ignore thirdparty javascript EXCEPT for security section?

Tags: sonarqube

Trying sonarqube 6.0

Hi sonarqube experts

I've used the `sonar.exclusion` in the past, but its all-or-nothing kind of deal.

Given the following sections in the sonarqube dashboard:

- Reliability
- Security
- Maintainability
- Duplications
- Size
- Complexity
- Documentation
- Issues

Is there a way to cross-filter selected directorys (such as those containing thirdparty javascript libraries) so they are *excluded except for* **Security** as an example?

Usecase is to, when configuring Quality Gates, to not worry about maintainability of thirdparty javascript libraries, but to very much worry about their vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Behind this request, I've the feeling that you're looking for a tool able to detect usages of API with known MITRE-CVE vulnerabilities. If this is the case, then SonarQube won't be of any help you covering this need.

Comment: we'll be working with HP Fortify via that plugin soon, however the context is focused on the Quality Gates and the 'dashboard' to quickly identify *items that need to be addressed* -- security/vulnerability of thirdparty libraries is a yes, but maintainability/duplicates/reliability no for the consuming project.